# Error al procesar imagen en power automate con power apps

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

En una aplicación se debe subir una foto a OneDrive. Hay dos posibilidades, haciéndola con la cámara o subiendo el archivo.

La lógica de la cámara es esta y funciona:

[image]

[image]

El flujo es el siguiente:

[image]

Al subir la foto en vez de hacerla al momento, da un error y no entiendo por qué si sigue usando un objeto Imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que muestra es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error:

> No se pueden procesar las expresiones de lenguaje de plantilla en las entradas de la acción "Compose_3" en la línea "1" y la columna "11685": "La función de lenguaje de plantilla "dataUriToBinary" espera que su parámetro tenga el formato de un URI de datos válido. El valor "appres://blobmanager/cb7e151d90374de88f0d714423f33842/1" que se ha proporcionado no tiene el formato correcto. Vea https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#dataUriToBinary para obtener detalles de uso.".

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

He descubierto el error. Es necesario parsear a JSON la foto antes de subirla, utilizando lo siguiente:

```
Set(BinaryImageData; Substitute(JSON(UploadImage.Image;JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData);"""";""));;
```